# Aura component documentation

Tags: lightning, aura

I am trying to do aura component documentation of my project with Inline description. Everything is working fine and I am able to see the documentation but when I go to aura doc I am also seeing cmp source tab, controller tab, helper tab... all the tabs we have on right panel as a tab in the documentation and when  I click on those tab, I can see the related code. I do not want this tab to show up on the documentation page. I want to hide this tabs which is broadcasting code.

I am attaching a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Based on my testing, removing the View Setup and Configuration profile permission removes a user's ability to view component documentation. Would this solve your issue? If not, who is it that you are wanting to not see your code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible on Lightning platform. You cannot customize the documentation site layout or tabs.